# Data to be populated from database on change of another dropdown in struts

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts, drop-down-menu, populate

I am developing a web application in struts in which I have two dropdowns on change of one other value should populate from database for that I have made use of javascript and servlet.

On change of first dropdown I call a servlet in that servlet I populate dropdown from database and writing the entire values in response stream like this:

```
  String buffer= "<select name='dwnfloor'><option value='0'>Select</option>";
     while(result.next())
                        {                 
                        buffer=buffer+
                           "<option value="+
                           result.getString("ID")+
                           ">"+
                           result.getString("name")+
                           "</option>";  
                    }  
                     buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
                     response.setContentType("text/html");
                     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                     /*response.getWriter().println(buffer); */
                     response.getWriter().write(buffer);`
```

But when it returns to the jsp page nothing comes in dropdown. I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: Without any idea how you're implementing it in the JSP it's impossible to help. This seems like the long way 'round, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree that your method is crude.

1. Call and get the value of the buffer string through an Ajax call.
2. Now put the combobox in a .
3. On Ajax call sucess , change the innerHTML of the div to your buffer string.

here is a pseudocode

```
oncomboxchange() {

    buffer = callAjax(){

}
if (ajaxcall success)
  combodiv.innerHTML = buffer

}
```